# How to get the number of the list in a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to get the number of the nested list that contains the particular number. This is my code:

```
listo = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
for x in listo:
    if 3 in x:
       print(len(x))
```

What I am trying to get here is the number of the nested list that has 3 in it. My code is returning 3 because I am of the function len, which is only returning the number of items inside the nested list that has the number. The output should be:

```
2
```

Since the number 3 is located on the second nested list. The count starts from 1, not 0.

How can I get the proper output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) specifying the start value as `1`:

```
listo = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
for i, x in enumerate(listo, 1):
    if 3 in x:
        print(i)

# 2
```

Comment: `enumerate(listo, 1)` instead of `i+1`

Comment: this approach does not short-circuit. Add a `break`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't think `break` is needed as OP is after finding positions of all sublists containing a `3`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
listo = [[1,2], [3,4,5]]

res = next(i for i, sublist in enumerate(listo) if 3 in sublist)
print(res)  # -> 1
```

Note that Python is 0-index languange; the first element on a list has index number 0. That is why the code above returns `1`. If you want to get `2`, well, just add `1` to that or, ever better, use the optional `start` parameter of enumerate (`enumerate(listo, 1)`).

To make the above *Error-proof*<sup>1</sup>, you can specify a default value to be returned in case `3` is not on any sublist.

```
res = next((i for i, sublist in enumerate(listo) if 3 in sublist), 'N\A')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `next` raises `StopIteration` if it exhausts the iterable without finding something to return, **unless** a default value is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate so as to get the index of the element in the array.

```
l1 = ["eat","sleep","repeat"]

# printing the tuples in object directly
for ele in enumerate(l1):
    print ele

Output:
(0, 'eat')
(1, 'sleep')
(2, 'repeat')
```

The same can be used for the code above.

```
listo = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
for ind,x in enumerate(listo):
     if 3 in x:
        print(ind)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). But if you are very new to coding this simple code is good.

Keep an extra variable (count) which will keep track of the index of the current list.

```
listo = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
count = 0
for x in listo:
    count += 1
    if 3 in x:
        print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `enumerate()`. `enumerate()` returns a (element count, element) pair:

```
for count, element in enumerate(listo):
    if 3 in element:
        print(count + 1)
        # Account for one-based indexing
```